# How to Connect MySQLiteDB.db by Using Terminal?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, terminal

How to Connect MySQLiteDB.db by Using Terminal?

I am beginner at SQLite DB...

Terminal

```
> sqlite3 MySQLiteDB.db
sqlite> .databases
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
sqlite> .tables
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
sqlite> .read MySQLiteDB.db
/*
// I Can See My SQLite DB Data
*/
```

How can I see tables or data in MySQLiteDB.db file?

MySQLiteDB.db file is already used in app. DB file have no problem.

I know only basic SQL Query (select, update, or delete)... but cannot access...

Comment: A lot of time, I collected the same error... are you sure that the MySQLiteDB.db was created with sqlite3 version? Moreover, be sure to use the last version of sqlite3.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I checked Xcode files. This file is sqlite3 version. And this app works well now.